# Trying to install Ruby 2.0.0 gives me "rvm: command not found" on Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I have discovered an issue/bug with the Ruby RVM so lets break down this issue bit by bit and hopefully find a resolution to this problem. So let's change this post to:

**UPDATING REDHAT LINUX SERVER'S RUBY FROM 1.8.4 TO 2.0.0**

**1.) We need to install RVM:**
In a nutshell here's what I've found out about this problem. First I could not get the

```
gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include="${MY_RUBY_HOME/rubies/src}"
```

command to work, the reason for this was due to not having the RVM installed on my linux server. So lets move on to the next step in getting a Redhat Linux server updated to Ruby 2.0.0

**2.) Installing RVM**

So we're going to require: https://rvm.io/rvm/install to get the RVM installed and as it turns out that there is an issue/bug that will not allow RVM to be installed on a RedHat Linux server.

When we try installing RVM, we use this command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

And we get the following information of the error here:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13784  100 13784    0     0  29723      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 29723
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch master
bash: line 133: which: command not found
bash: line 116: rvm_error: command not found

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '200'.
```

Here is the link to this issue opened at github.com: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2121

**3.)A Possible Solution?**

Here's something I would propose to fix this problem, would it be possible to install RVM by copying these files from rvm-stable.tar.gz to their appropriate directories on a server? And by that I mean, why not install it manually?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not configured rvm properly. Install rvm and than try installing ruby.
You can follow the link to install and configure rvm properly.

https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: When I tried installing rvm I got this error:  Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch master
bash: line 133: which: command not found
bash: line 116: rvm_error: command not found

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '200'.

Comment: This then sounds very much like question posted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179648/cant-install-rvm-on-redhat-linux-server Looking at the poster, I see this is you.  You could update the question to bring it up to date.