# Can't install RVM on Redhat Linux Server

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, redhat

I need to install RVM in order to get my copy of Ruby updated to 2.0.0

I've tried this following command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

But it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13784  100 13784    0     0  34419      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 34419
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch master
bash: line 133: which: command not found
bash: line 116: rvm_error: command not found

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '200'.
```

Comment: Can you try "sudo yum install which" then retry

Comment: Is this a continuation of your [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18179432/485864)?  It looks like you may not have satisfied the [requirements](http://rvm.io/rvm/prerequisites) for installing RVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just found an issue and an bug, they should be reported to RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2121  Thanks, I've just opened an issue about this here. Hopes this sheds some light on anyone else experiencing this problem.